# For existing angular 5 app: Can I use only cordova to make it mobile app?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, nativescript

I have an existing web app using angular 5 and angular materials and I want to make it a mobile app.

I've heard that I have to use (Ionic + Cordova) to make it into mobile app, but I also heard that I will have to drop angular material and routing and maybe re-design my web app ...

so, I have 3 question:-

1. if I don't need any plugin, can I make it a mobile app with using only cordova "without any changes"? (as an app in playstore not as PWA).
2. Is the right approach for Ionic is to start with developing the mobile app and then It will work also as a website without any changes?
3. does NativeScript Requires the same amount of work for existing web app as Ionic? or more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I don't need any plugin, can I make it a mobile app with using only cordova "without any changes"? (as an app in playstore not as PWA).

You will still be required to make a few changes in your app such as bootstrapping the Angular when cordova device is ready. But you can add check like if cordova is available then do this otherwise do that.

**But please note, the performance of the app will not be up to the mark as Ionic because Ionic do various changes to Angular to make it faster and compatible with mobile devices**

> Is the right approach for Ionic is to start with developing the mobile app and then It will work also as a website without any changes?

In a way, yes. Because Ionic is a mobile first framework. So you should start with Ionic (porting from Angular 5 to Ionic will not be a headache) and then make it work like a website.

> does NativeScript Requires the same amount of work for existing web app as Ionic? or more?

What do you meant by NativeScript? If you are asking about native plugins supported by Cordova/Ionic, then using native plugins will be a cakewalk.

Comment: thank very much, but for the "performance", is it gonna be really slow or will be the same as the web app?

Comment: It will not be really slow but you can be able to judge it as compared to Ionic app performance.

Comment: "What do you mean by NativeScript" - https://docs.nativescript.org/start/introduction

Comment: I heard with NativeScript you only need to create xml view instead of html and you will have a native cross-platform mobile app plus your web app. any idea about the amount of work compared to Ionic?